# How to install Unix commands on a Jail broken iPhone (ie tail)

Tags: iphone, unix, logging, jailbreak

I'm doing extensive log analysis on my jail broken iPhone.. unfortunately some of the key Unix commands are missing like tail etc.. How can I install it on my jail broken iPhone?

Comment: I'd recommend going into Cydia, and searching for packages that have the string "cmds" in them.  There's a bunch, and most Unix developers would want to have them all.  I have `tail` on my phone, I just can't remember exactly which package gave it to me.  Also, on future questions, try to explain how you need stuff like this to perform a programming task, otherwise the cleaning ladies will stop by and get rid of your question.

Comment: @Nate I thought the programming task was sufficiently described.. basically analyzing log statements.. so i run something like `%logfile% tail -f` and view the logs on a shell window in real time..

Comment: It was sufficiently described for me.  As you see, I wasn't one of the 5 who closed the question.  I personally dislike the OCD manner with which privileged users purge questions ... I'm just offering guidance on how to avoid closure in the future.  For what it's worth, I've upvoted your question, as I consider it useful and clear.

Comment: @Nate thanks so much for the up vote :) and also for your comment.. I care a whole lot about keeping my questions within the approved scope of SOF and thanks for providing some direction in that regard (but seriously though.. 5 people closed this question? wow.. lol)

Comment: For anyone looking, you can find the "tail" command in package "Core Utilities" in Cydia.